# kdb/q: pass the return table to the function again, with another static table and iterator i

Tags: kdb

Say I have a function `f` and three variables: one empty table `A` (need to insert each row sequentially), one static table `B` and an iterator `i`.

```
B: ([] rdn: 6 2 5 3 2 3 8; col2: 7#`remove;
A:1#B;
f:{[x;y;z] 
 temp_a: select from x where i = (max i);
 temp_b: select from y where i = z;
 if[(exec first rdn from temp_b) > (exec first rdn from temp_a); x: x upsert temp_b];
 :0!x;
};
```

Starting from row 2 (i = 2), I want to get the row `i` from B and compared to the last row of A. I will only insert the record if `(A[last row; rdn] < B[i; rdn] && B[i; col2] = remove)`.

This is my desired outcome:

| rdn | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | remove |
| 8 | remove |

My first attempt was to do `raze{[x; y; z] f[x;y;z]}[A; B; ] each (exec distinct i from B)` which doesn't work since it doesn't update A.

My second attempt was using over (`/`) `{[x;y;z] f[x;y;z]}/[A; B; exec distinct i from B]` which is definitely not right either.

I am not sure how I can reuse updated A back in the function again. I searched for hours and haven't seen a relevant post that solves the exact problem.

Comment: could you provide clearer step by step pseudo code, its not clear to me what the intended behaviour is in the case i-1 is outside of the range of A

Comment: Thanks Matt. I did set A to be the first row of B to start with before the iteration. `A:1#B`; The goal is essentially to loop through each row of B and create a new record based on the previous update from A and the new values from B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want the rows in B for which `rdn` is greater than the previous `rdn` AND col2=remove? If so then you wouldn't need to iterate, you could do something like:

```
q){select from x where test}update test:(col2=`remove)&(>)prior rdn from B
rdn col2   test
---------------
6   remove 1
8   remove 1
```

EDIT: or if it's the *running maximum* you need, then:

```
q)select from B where rdn=maxs rdn
rdn col2
----------
6   remove
8   remove
```

If your problem is more complex than you're explaining, and you really must iterate through every row of the table, then you could go with something like:

```
q)distinct{$[x[`rdn]<y`rdn;y;x]}\[B]
rdn col2
----------
6   remove
8   remove
```

Comment: Thanks Terry. Although the rdn could be `6 2 3 2 5 8` in table B, and I would imagine your solution would take `6 3 5 8` since these numbers would be bigger than previous values. That's why I started a new table A as my desired outcome is `6 8` and skip any intermediate values if not bigger than what's being recorded in A.

Comment: I am working with more complicated tables but i simplified them as A and B in this case. Unfortunately, i do need to loop through B and take both updated A and B back to the function again for the next iteration. :(

Comment: So you need the running maximum then? `select from B where rdn=maxs rdn` ? Edited my answer